# ---BEGIN __ KEY-----' and '-----END __ KEY-----' Copy public key

Tags: windows

Hey i have been wondering about how to copy and paste someone's public key and i don't know if I have a add the following with the key /  ----BEGIN __ KEY-----' and '-----END __ KEY-----'   or do I just need to copy the key it's self
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

Those BEGIN and END lines are normal parts of "PEM encoding", which is the most common format for storing things like keys or certificates in text form.

It's best to keep those lines, as it will help most software that expects PEM formatted keys, to realize what kind of key you're pasting in. If you run across any software that expects PEM format keys and isn't smart enough to deal with the BEGIN/END lines, then it's pretty crappy software. Unfortunately, there's a lot of crappy software in the PKI world, so it wouldn't surprise me if sometimes you have to strip the lines off manually.